# Google Tag Manager "Now Editing" environment contains old tags and variables

Tags: google-tag-manager

My development environment has the tag for the "Now Editing" version of my container.

But my development environment is firing tags that I removed from GTM a few versions ago. I'd like to understand why that's happening.

I have tried disabling my cache using Chrome Developer Tools. I have verified that gtm.js actually contains the tags and variables that shouldn't be there any more.

The top of gtm.js has this:

```
// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
// Container Version: 0
(function(w, g) {
```

I'm not sure whether the "Version: 0" here is related to the problem.

My production environment isn't firing the removed tags.

Sorry I haven't provided much info here, but I'm not sure what else would be useful.

Comment: Were you the only one doing gtm or have others done it?

Comment: Others have worked on it in the past, but I'm the only one who's made any changes the last few months.

Comment: If it is still saying version 0 that means no one has published version 1. That means you're not making any changes. This sounds like you don't have an administration account. Is that right?

Comment: I have been making changes, and I have View and Manage permissions. Version 16 is published and Version 17 is "Now Editing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around my problem by creating a Custom Environment, and publishing my changes to this environment. I still don't know why the "Now Editing" default environment was showing very old versions of some tags.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go into the tag manager and check your original code snippet. Match that with what is in your test site. Check to see if two snippets have been running on your development environment it might be that when it was originally set up someone thought it may be a good idea to have a second set but then scrapping that idea later.

Of the 3 lines that you've posted of code, two of those lines are just comments and as such are not read by the computer so where you see

```
//this is a comment
```

That is being ignored.

The third line looks like an unfinished function. I would comment out the third line to see if that fixes your problem

```
// double slash will comment out.
```

If that does fix it completely remove the line (after thorough testing).

It might be that you may need to replace the code snippet by deleting the old one and replacing it with a new one, or delete a secondary code snippet.

Also and I mention it for completeness but did you transition to universal analytics or are you on classic? I would make sure to upgrade of you haven't.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I checked, and I only have one GTM snippet. I am aware of Javascript syntax, and I know that the snippet I posted was incomplete. The snippet was from gtm.js which is generated by GTM, so I cannot directly edit it. I am using Universal Analytics.